# Построение графиков div'ами - рационально ли?

Tags: php, html, изображения, графика

После реализации графиков посредством GD и её функций, и её, не очень широкой на сегодняшний день кастомизацией, подумал, а можно ли реализовывать вывод графиков по средствам обычных блоков (div'ов). Размер блоков задать, пожалуй труда ни для какого не составит.
Но вот рационально ли это?
Есть ли реализации? *(доп. автора: есть - вспомнил про Википедию.)*
Заметил, что при рисовании графиков более, чем на 100 значений через GD, значительно напрягается PHP и скрипт работает уже не шустро.
(нарисовать 100 блоков и покрасить в html для php вообще не составит труда)
Одним словом хочу услышать доводы за и против в адрес того или иного субъекта данного вопроса.
**(Вопрос актуален для линейных графиков с выводом одного массива данных!)**
Пример как на рис.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**(Добавлю: я имел ввиду без использования сторонних библиотек типа charts, google.developers и flotr2)**

Comment: может лучше `svg` или `canvas` ?

Comment: про `div` – думаю не рационально, нагрузка на DOM большая, позиционирование не точное

Comment: Думаю метод вполне хорош, учитывая что можно через css на каждый ткой div навесить разные украшательства вроде теней, градиентов и рамок и  т.п. и всё это будет делать браузер автоматически с каждым блоком. Только если блоков не слишком много, чтобы браузер не повесить.

Comment: А почему бы не рендерить графики на клиенте с помощью JS? Существует куча библиотек для этого, и не нужно изобретать велосипедом.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev , Я любитель изобретать велосипеды. И велосипеды тоже нужно модернизировать постоянно, особенно свои. И я не сторонник обвешивать проекты множеством сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @sercxjo , кстати хорошая идея. Протестировать одинаковые графики в разной реализации. Надо на досуге собрать div'ный график.

Comment: построение графиков без использования сторонних библиотек подобно построению графиков с использованием сторонних библиотек , но только без сторонних библиотек )

Comment: @I_CaR, на создание качественных библиотек для построения графиков уже потрачены десятки тысяч человеко-часов. У вас физически не хватит времени (и, возможно, квалификации) на построение качественного аналога. А плодить велосипеды из костылей -- путь в никуда.

Comment: @korytoff, для прямоугольников между div и svg разница только в поддержке браузерами и у svg она хуже. Или имелось в виду svg-изображение? Вроде так никто не делает. А ещё предлагаю за переоткрытие проголосовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy вот тут поясняется – http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882716/html5-canvas-vs-svg-vs-div/5883032#5883032

Comment: @korytoff, сравнения svg с div'ами там нет, кроме того, что дивам нельзя придать произвольную форму. А что канвас быстрее вроде естественно.

Comment: @Qwertiy как это? Там как раз svg, div и canvas обсуждают. Canvas понятное дело выигрывает

Comment: @korytoff, "I made Canvas and HTML DIV test pages, both had movable "nodes."" - где тут про svg? И 100000 dom-элементов - это что-то перебор. Там не говорится, что 100000 svg-прямоугольников работают лучше. А ещё там 2013 год - данные могли уже и устареть.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, тестов прямых не было, я про общее сравнение в тексте в целом

Answer (score 5):

Построить серию `div`'ов, иллюстрирующих массив значений – вполне простой рабочий вариант. Пусть php отдаёт сами данные, а график рисует браузер. Если число значений в одном графике до неск. тысяч – для браузера не должно вызвать проблем.

Без библиотек, взять и написать несколько строк – будет график.

Вы его покажете заказчику. И тот попросит, а давайте оси добавим. И подписи под значениями. Значений много, поэтому подписи лишь каждому N-ому. И чтобы они вертикально были. И горизонтальные линии каждую 1000. Нет, каждые 1500. И всплывающие подсказки при наведении мышки. И т.д. – фантазия хорошо работает, глядя на живой график.

В такой ситуации вы напишете в итоге свою библиотеку. Поэтому, может, лучше сразу взять пушку и бахнуть по воробьям? Скажем, мой любимый [D3.js](http://d3js.org/), где уже предусмотрены и реализованы даже фишки, на которые у заказчика фантазии не хватит. Для вашей задачи вот [пример простого bar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) на нём.

Answer (score 3):

может не вник в вопрос - но графики традиционно рисуются js. при помощи php\ajax получаете массив точек и отображаете. в div. библиотек тьма ну вот

[довольно простая](http://www.flotcharts.org/) и [покруче](http://www.highcharts.com/)

по второй даж [писал](http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2014/07/highcharthighstock.html)